Android Studio: Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource'
I updated android gradle plugin to 8.4.1 by following the correct steps.
Unfortunately I am unable to build the project succesfully and get the following errorss:
Execution failed for task ':core-test:mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction

Execution failed for task ':core-test:mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 6 files found with path 'META-INF/LICENSE.md' from inputs:
      - .gradle/caches/transforms-4/5ea3c579d80340616bdea040fc30aa66/transformed/jetified-junit-jupiter-params-5.8.2.jar
      -.gradle/caches/transforms-4/4972705b1c84fbd70517cdfa49d5064a/transformed/jetified-junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar
      - /.gradle/caches/transforms-4/024fa65130402e8b1374d12c1fc233ee/transformed/jetified-junit-jupiter-api-5.8.2.jar
      - .gradle/caches/transforms-4/5f1e0de7845fa5b5f50c40db7da9f291/transformed/jetified-junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar
      - .gradle/caches/transforms-4/a5187c085e0e6a340e17f4107b1dfcf3/transformed/jetified-junit-platform-commons-1.8.2.jar
      - .gradle/caches/transforms-4/bcc1d77dfa47f2bd37c56aa95ee58592/transformed/jetified-junit-jupiter-5.8.2.jar
     Adding a packaging block may help, please refer to
     https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/Packaging
     for more information



I have already updated included "META-INF/LICENSE.md" in packaging options and tried most online solutions like
deleting .gradle entirely and redownloading + building, changing java sdk path from default to amazon cornertto or Azul Zulu.
I have also updated permissions of "/Library/Application Support/kotlin/daemon" and java sdk path to 755

Hi Khushboo Gandhi, I'm facing the exact same error with Gradle 8.10. Have you found a solution ?
